# CListCtrl - how to enable multiple selection

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-mobile, clistctrl

I am creating a MFC application for Windows Mobile and don't know how to enable multiple selection for List Control (CListCtrl). In properties panel Single Selection is set to False but still can't select multiple items.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never targeted Windows Mobile but you might try the following:

> list.ModifyStyle(LVS_SINGLESEL, 0);

Comment: Actually the problem was AlwaysShowSelection Property which has to be set TRUE - it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

ModifyStyle method of CWnd base will work (see post from Diego) if you desire to do this programmatically OR you can define the attribute within the Resource Editor IF your placing the control on a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

All ListView window styles are defined in the `CommCtrl.h` header file. Check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles) on Microsoft's website.

The default setting for a ListView control allows multiple selections. If you need to allow only single selection from the list, then use below code:

```
m_ListControl.ModifyStyle(NULL, LVS_SINGLESEL, 0);
```

`m_ListControl` is the variable for your List Control. You can many other styles mentioned on above page.

Here is another example:

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_LIST1), LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
```