# Clistctrl selection detect

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, wtl, clistctrl

I've been playing with the list view and came across this post: [How to detect a CListCtrl selection change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462895/how-to-detect-a-clistctrl-selection-change#comment12034791_1466086)

However the code used there has a major flow, it doesn't work with multiple selection (as pointed out in that thread). So my question is how can I make the code work with multiselection (eg. selection with shift or ctrl)?

Comment: Does this not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464675/clistctrl-how-to-enable-multiple-selection there is a comment there about AlwaysShowSelection Property in the comments to the accepted answer

Comment: AlwaysShowSelection didn't work. It only kept the selection when the list view was out of focus. The main problem is that the function will not catch a change when you select multiple rows with shift, and then select one of them (which deselects the other ones).

Comment: If that is the only situation it doesn't detect, then can't you simply catch a button click, and check the selection in order to fix the behavior?

Comment: `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notification gets you all notifications, including for multiply selected items. Code snippet there does possibly wrong `if` to get into "do stuff".

Answer (score 0):

I've written a handy function to see if your OnItemChanged notification was due to a selection change:

```
BOOL IsItemSelChanged(NMLISTVIEW* pNMListView)
{
    // call this from your OnItemchangedMyListCtrl function in your dialog class

    if(!(pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE))
    {
        return(FALSE);
    }

    if((pNMListView->uOldState & LVIS_SELECTED) == (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED))
    {
        return(FALSE);
    }

    return(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Handle `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` and `LVN_ODSTATECHANGED`, all you needed...

> If a list-view control has the LVS_OWNERDATA style, and the user
> selects a range of items by holding down the SHIFT key and clicking
> the mouse, LVN_ITEMCHANGED notifications are not sent for each
> selected or deselected item. Instead, you will receive a single
> LVN_ODSTATECHANGED notification, indicating that a range of items has
> changed state.